# Google map as background in Bootstrap carousel not displaying entirely

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, carousel

I try to add a map as item in Bootstap carousel,in the same way as in this topic [Google map with bootstrap 3 carousel bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744401/google-map-with-bootstrap-3-carousel-bug) ,when the map is on the first item(active),the map is displayed correctly,but when the map is placed on the second position(2nd item,3rd....),the map is not displayed entirely.

here is the demo to explain what's going wrong:
http://www.bootply.com/9nAZmtYLOM#
And here the demo of what's going right:
http://www.bootply.com/YcaTxtftSW

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: map needs element dimensions to render properly but hidden elements have no dimensions. Could try using map refresh method when it is exposed. See docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `.item` is hidden when map is set you will have to resize the map when the section becomes visible

You can call the resize event after slide

```
 $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if($('.item.active').find("#map-canvas").length == 1) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    }
 });
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Hwml8WMIPn)

Comment: Thank I tried this approach ,but doesnt work   $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if($(e.relatedTarget).find("#map-canvas").length == 1) {
 
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    }
 });

Comment: Change `slide.bs.carousel` to `slid.bs.carousel`

Comment: @Alex Cool. `relatedTarget` works for slide and not slid so it was messing things up.